# Getting Modules Into Python Search Path

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

In the past, in order for me to use/import my own custom packages in python all i've had to do is edit my .bash_profile so that they are appended to my $PATH environmental variable.

```
>> echo $PATH
/Users/MYNAME/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/MYNAME/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/Users/MYNAME/Documents/Python_Programs/MYPACKAGE1:/Users/MYNAME/Documents/GitRepos/MYPACKAGE2
```

as you can see my path variable contains MYPACKAGE1 and MYPACKAGE2.
The former is literally just a folder with a single .py file in it. The latter follows the conventional package folder structure.

One thing to note is my PYTHONPATH is apparently empty

```
>> echo $PYTHONPATH

>>
```

but if, in python, I look at `sys.path`:

```
>> import sys
>> sys.path
['',
 '/Users/MYNAME/anaconda/bin',
 '/Users/MYNAME/anaconda/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Users/MYNAME/anaconda/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/MYNAME/anaconda/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/MYNAME/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/Users/MYNAME/Documents/Python_Programs/MYPACKAGE1',
 '/Users/MYNAME/Documents/GitRepos/MYPACKAGE2',
 '/Users/MYNAME/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Sphinx-1.5.6-py3.6.egg',
 '/Users/MYNAME/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aeosa',
 '/Users/MYNAME/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/Users/MYNAME/.ipython']
```

Great, no problem importing from either package.

So I made a third package which has the same structure as MYPACKAGE2

```
MYPACKAGE3/
    bin/
    README.md
    CHANGES.txt
    setup.py
    MANIFEST.IN
    my_module/
        __init__.py
        sub_module1.py
        sub_module2.py
```

added it to my path

```
>> echo $PATH
/Users/MYNAME/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/MYNAME/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/Users/MYNAME/Documents/Python_Programs/MYPACKAGE1:/Users/MYNAME/Documents/GitRepos/MYPACKAGE2:/Users/MYNAME/Documents/GitRepos/MYPACKAGE3
```

but for some reason i can't import it in python and it's not in my sys.path (sys.path is exactly the same as before).

```
>> import my_module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'
```

I have no idea what's changed. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that my `$PATH` variable has nothing to do with it. To clarify, I'm using python 3.6, so it may be different in 2.7.

It turns out there was a `.pth` file in my anaconda/.../site-packages directory that I must have created a long time ago. It looks like the `sys.path` gets populated not only by the .../site-packages directory, but also by all directories listed in any `.pth` files within that directory (or it looks like any directory in sys.path re [the hitchikers guide to packaging](http://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html)).

> **Python file layout**
>
> A Python installation has a site-packages directory inside the module directory. This directory is where user installed packages are dropped. A .pth file in this directory is maintained which contains paths to the directories where the extra packages are installed.

I know this question is somewhat esoteric - but hope it helps other stragglers trying to understand the import system.

Answer (score 0):

Your echo $PATH has

```
"Users/MYNAME/Documents/GitRepos/MYPACKAGE3"
```

and not

```
"/Users/MYNAME/Documents/GitRepos/MYPACKAGE3".
```

Looks like you missed "/" in the beginning.

To add a custom path to sys.path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/MYNAME/Documents/GitRepos/MYPACKAGE3/")
```

or in BASH:

```
-bash-4.1$export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/Users/MYNAME/Documents/GitRepos/MYPACKAGE3/"
```

And then try importing your module.

Comment: sorry that was a typo - it is definitely there.

Comment: Paste your sys.path after adding 3rd package path and the error you faced while importing package.

Comment: sys.path is exactly the same as before. and posted the ModuleNotFound error

Comment: @RSHAP Edited the answer to add a custom path to sys.path

Comment: this does work but i'd rather not have to do that for every script that uses my package. And I'm very confused as why it works for my other two packages but not this one...

Comment: additionally I believe changing my bash_profile to add it to $PYTHONPATH instead of $PATH also works... but again... why didn't I have to do that previously

Comment: also... downvote was not me ... just saying - appreciate ur help

Comment: If you just want me to help in importing your module either you can add your path to sys.path or  to PYTHONPATH in bash profile. If that is not your question and if you want to find out why it worked earlier and not now I am not sure I can answer that. Sorry!. There may be so many reasons which caused that issue.